# bash to update filename in directory based on partial match to another

Tags: bash

I am trying to use `bash` to rename/update the filename of a text file in `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/percent` based on a partial match of digits with another text file in `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/analysis.txt`.  The match will always be in either lines 3,4,or 5 of this file. I am not able to do this but hopefully the 'bash` below is a start.  Thank you :).

**text file in `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/percent`** - there could be a maximum of 3 files in this directory

```
00-0000_fbn1_20xcoverage.txt
```

**text file in `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/analysis.txt`**

```
status: complete
id names: 
00-0000_Last-First
01-0101_LastN-FirstN
02-0202_La-Fi
```

**desired result in `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/percent`**

```
00-0000_Last-First_fbn1_20xcoverage.txt
```

**bash**

```
for filename in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/percent/*.txt; do echo mv \"$filename\" \"${filename//[0-9]-[0-9]/}\"; done < /home/cmccabe/Desktop/analysis.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a proper [Process-Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst#process_substitution) syntax with a `while-loop`,

You can run the script under `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/percent`

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ needed for associative array

# declare the associative array
declare -A mapArray

# Read the file from the 3rd line of the file and create a hash-map
# as mapArray[00-0000]=00-0000_Last-First and so on.

while IFS= read -r  line; do
    mapArray["${line%_*}"]="$line"
done < <(tail -n +3 /home/cmccabe/Desktop/analysis.txt)

# Once the hash-map is constructed, rename the text file accordingly.
# echo the file and the name to be renamed before invoking the 'mv' 
# command        

for file in *.txt; do
    echo "$file" ${mapArray["${file%%_*}"]}"_${file#*_}"
    # mv "$file" ${mapArray["${file%%_*}"]}"_${file#*_}"

done
```

Comment: Thank you both very much :).

Comment: This solution is a kind of porting "awk" code to bash code!

Answer (score 1):

This is another similar bash approach:

```
while IFS="_" read -r id newname;do
#echo "id=$newid - newname=$newname"  #for cross check 
oldfilename=$(find . -name "${id}*.txt" -printf %f)
[ -n "$oldfilename" ] && echo mv \"$oldfilename\" \"${id}_${newname}_${oldfilename#*_}\";
done < <(tail -n+3 analysis)
```

We read the analysis file and we split each line (i.e 00-0000_Last-First) to two fields using `_` as delimiter:
id=00-000
newname=Last-First

Then using this file id we read from file "analysis" we check (using find) to see if a file exists starting with the same id.
If such a file exists, it's filename is returned in variable $oldfilename.
If this variable is not empty then we do the mv.
tail -n+3 is used to ignore the first three lines of the file results.txt

[Test this solution online here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaHhNOWNaLWc2ZjQ)